# Orderer Service Peer and Smart Contract

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, smartcontracts

My names is Antonio and i come from Italy. In this days i'm designing an fabric architecture for an important project.
My network will have one channel that represents a community of n peer. This latter can endor the transaction and to do basic operations.In that community there will be and Administrator.
is The ordere a physical peer where someone have that role? In that case i will define the Community Manager responsable for the Channel configuration, network configuration and as orderer.
The administrator will receive the reward from external national institutions. The idea is to distribute that reward to the peer in the community with a smart contract.
The Administrator, therefore orderer, will receive the reward then the smart contract automatically distribute the reward based on some parameters. The question is:

The smart contract can receive the events from orderer, therefore administrator network and channel, of reward received and automatically distribute the reward?

Antonioy

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

you probably misunderstand a bit how the Hyperledger Fabric works. The orderer is a separate entity and it receives transaction candidates from the peers putting them into blocks and them broadcasting these blocks in a specific order (that's why it's called "Orderer"). You can not receive events from the orderer inside the chaincode (the name of smart contracts in Fabric) and the chaincode is agnostic to what peers it is being run on, you can only   work with an identity of a signer of a transaction that has been sent to a peer for endorsement.

Comment: Thanks. For me it is all new. I thought this. I have organization and this one it will be a Manager of the community. This organization will have two nodes; the orderer only for ording the transactions and the another node as peer with smart contract. I thought with this peer I will manage event with smart contract.